# Linker error "clang error linker command failed"

Tags: c++, xcode, clang, linker-errors

There are quite a few posts like this on Stack Overflow, but most of them pertain to [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode), and I cannot replicate their solutions. I have a *Heap.h*, *Heap.cpp*, and *main.cpp* file and whenever I try to run *main.cpp* with `g++ main.cpp Heap.cpp`, it gives me:

> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

#### File *Heap.h*

```cpp
#ifndef _HEAP_H_
#define _HEAP_H_

template<class T>
class Heap{
    private:
        struct Node{
            T *dist;
            T *v;

            bool operator==(const Node& a){
                return *dist == *(a -> dist);
            }

            bool operator!=(const Node& a){
                return (!(*dist == *(a -> dist)));
            }

        };

        Node *container;
        int size;
        int curSize;
        T sourceV;

    public:
        Heap();
        Heap(int inSize, T inSourceV);

};

#endif
```

#### File *Heap.cpp*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include "Heap.h"

using namespace std;

template<class T>
Heap<T>::Heap(){
    cout << "hello" <<endl;
}

template<class T>
Heap<T>::Heap(int inSize, T inSourceV){
    size = inSize;
    container = new Node[size];
    curSize = 0;
    sourceV = inSourceV;

    int maxVal = numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        container[i].dist = &maxVal;
        container[i].v = &maxVal;
    }
}
```

#### File *main.cpp*

```cpp
#include "Heap.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   Heap <int> h;
}
```

It is strange I have another project that contains *bst.h*, *bst.cpp*, and *main.cpp*, and those run fine. The difference between these two projects is that the *bst* I implemented is not a templated class.

I also saw another similar post that mentioned something about changing bitcode settings, but where can I access that from?

I'm running Xcode 7.1. Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76). 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0 
Thread model: posix

Comment: Did you try what the message suggests? Call with -v and see what was actually happening there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't instantiate a `Heap<int>` in the `Heap.cpp` compilation. As a result the compiler doesn't bother generating *any* code for `Heap.o`.

You can see this if you do:

```
nm Heap.o
```

It tells you there's nothing there.

This is a typical behaviour of a C++ compiler - no template gets turned into code unless there's an instantiation of it.

Quick solutions are

1. Move all the Heap.cpp code into the template class declaration of `Heap.h`
2. create a dummy function in `Heap.cpp` that instantiates a `Heap<int>`

Comment: Never would have caught this. Just curious, is that why there are some templated classes that end in `.inl` instead of `.cpp`? To get around this instantiation problem? Because if we would have to instantiate Heap to a specific type, wouldn't this defeat the purpose of templates?

Comment: The use of `.inl` is only a hint for developers. It implies that the code should be inlined e.g. by `#include` in a `.cpp` file, but that's only an expectation.  Templates are just that - a template. They don't resolve into actual code until the template is instantiated. As a result; a template on it's own can't be split between a `.h` and `.cpp` file; as without instantiation; there won't be any code created that can be linked to.

Comment: the quick solutions you mentioned, is one better than the other?

Comment: The most correct solution is moving the template code into the `.h`. The second will only solve the problem of `Heap<int>` in that case, and if you create a `Heap<float>` then it wouldn't work. I only classed it as *quick* because there's very little code in there to move.

Comment: Another hack is just explicit instantiation by including "template Heap<int>;"  in the definitions file. Suffers the same problem as a dummy function as it only instantiates the <int> template. It all should be in the header.

Comment: I've got everything in the .h file, how would I instantiate it in main.cpp? I tried several variations of `Heap<int> h(2,2)` and none work.

Comment: Ok, so your `Heap.h` code has the `template<class T>
Heap<T>::Heap() {}` code and the `template<class T>
Heap<T>::Heap(int inSize, T inSourceV){}` definitions in the `.h`, you don't have any content in the `Heap.cpp` file because it's all moved into `Heap.h`.

Comment: [A reference for `nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm).